# How to backup and restore informix db using Onbar tool with ONPSM cloud storage device?

Tags: backup, cloud, ibm, informix

I am having a hard time using the Onbar tool (which relies on Onpsm primary storage manager for Informix db (server 12.1) using the cloud device (AWS s3).

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.bar.doc/ids_bar_526.htm

1. On the backup server, I have created a a DBSPOOL and LOGPOOL devices using commands similar to the following

> ```
> onpsm -D add AMAZON1 \
> -g DBSPOOL \
> -p HIGHEST \
> -t CLOUD \
> --url https://ifmx-s3-dev.s3.amazonaws.com \
> --provider S3 \
> --user AKIAIT1111155555X4PA \ 
> --password A2nB21111155555nvTI0X9ZxGzUJNJivoBQY9MrD \
> --container ifmx-s3-dev \
> --max_part_size 25600
> ```

2. I then setup a cron job to perform a standard, level-0 backup of all online storage spaces and used logical logs.

> onbar -b -L 0
>
> onbar -b -l

3. Reading the following IBM publication which advises to backup the storage catalog tables since are not backed up with the database instance, I set up a cron job to backup the $INFORMIXDIR/etc/psm which is supposed to contain the storage catalog tables

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.bar.doc/ids_bar_526.htm

Copied $INFORMIXDIR/etc/psm directory and $INFORMIXDIR/etc/ixbar.? from the source server to the target and renamed the  ixbar.? file replacing the IBM Informix server name that is used on the source computer with the IBM Informix server name of the target computer.

3- Changed ownership of the copied /psm directory and the ixbar file to user informix

4- Shutdown the db to perform a cold restore

```
onmode -yuk
```

5- Checked that the backup objects are there

```
onpsm -O list
```

6- Attempted to restore data and the critical files during the cold restore

```
onbar -r -cf yes
```

Got this weird error:

> the environment variable BAR_BSALIB_PATH must be set in order to use
>   the -cf option!
>
> I checked the BAR_BSALIB_PATH in the ONCONFIG file and it is set to
>   $INFORMIXDIR/lib/libbsapsm.so
>   Even done this
>   BAR_BSALIB_PATH="/opt/informix-12.10.fc10/lib/libbsapsm.so"
>   :/home/informix echo $BAR_BSALIB_PATH
>   /opt/informix-12.10.fc10/lib/libbsapsm.so
>
> Still the same error!

7- Regenerate the emergency boot file - If the ixbar file is not empty and contains object data, onsmsync -b updates the sysutils database and the ixbar file so that they are in sync.

```
onsmsync -b
```

bar_act.log

> 2018-07-20 00:19:07 25656  25370 (-43207) Unable to open connection to
>   database server: .  2018-07-20 00:19:07 25656  25370 onsmsync
>   complete, returning 155 (0x9b)  2018-07-20 00:21:24 25933  25931
>   /opt/informix-12.10.fc10/bin/onbar_d -r

8- Restore the data

```
onbar -r
```

Warning: Parameter's user-configured value was adjusted. (ALARMPROGRAM)
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file

9- The server came back in fast recovery mode

10 - **bar_dbug.log**

> GET /awwdst13a/rootdbs/0/rootdbs.377.1 HTTP/1.1
>
> then failure messages like
>   * Failed writing body (0 != 16347)
>   * Closing connection 0  2018-07-20 00:21:25 25937  25933 smtranid.c:155 Object Transaction List was empty.  2018-07-20 00:21:27
>   25933  25931 bar_ixbar_list: enter  2018-07-20 00:21:27 25933  25931
>   bar_ixbar_list: return 0 (0x00)  2018-07-20 00:21:27 25933  25931
>   bar_build_timeline: enter  2018-07-20 00:21:27 25933  25931
>   bar_build_timeline: return 0 (0x00)  2018-07-20 00:21:27 25933  25931
>   smcatalog.c:521 nsmOpenDatabase: Count: opened = 9, missing = 0. 
>   2018-07-20 00:21:27 25933  25931 smtranid.c:84 Object Transaction List
>   was empty.  2018-07-20 00:21:27 25941  25933 smcatalog.c:521
>   nsmOpenDatabase: Count: opened = 9, missing = 0.  2018-07-20 00:21:27
>   25941 filter        write_to_filter: Write failed on parent's output
>   pipe. errno = 32..  2018-07-20 00:21:27 25941 filter
>   write_to_filter: Error writing to handle/fd 17 located at 0x1e05930.

11- **bar_act.log**

> 2018-07-20 00:21:27 25945  25933 Successfully connected to Storage
>   Manager.  2018-07-20 00:21:27 25933  25931 Begin cold level 0 restore
>   rootdbs (Storage Manager copy ID: 0 377).  2018-07-20 00:21:40 25945 
>   25933 Informix Primary Storage Manager session 867 closed  2018-07-20
>   00:21:40 25945  25933 The child process for the backup and restore
>   filter is terminating  with exit code 0.  2018-07-20 00:21:41 25933 
>   25931 Completed cold level 0 restore rootdbs.
>
> 2018-07-20 00:21:41 25969  25933 Begin cold level 0 restore api7dbs
>   (Storage Manager copy ID: 0 381).  2018-07-20 00:21:42 25968  25933
>   Informix Primary Storage Manager session 869 opened.  2018-07-20
>   00:21:42 25968  25933 Successfully connected to Storage Manager. 
>   2018-07-20 00:21:42 25968  25933 Starting Filter /usr/bin/gunzip. 
>   2018-07-20 00:21:42 25968  25933 Informix Primary Storage Manager
>   session 869 closed
>
> 2018-07-20 00:21:44 25971  25933 Begin cold level 0 restore dat2dbs
>   (Storage Manager copy ID: 0 380).  2018-07-20 00:21:51 25983  25971
>   There are no more bytes to read.
>                                     ISAM Error = 0.
>                                     OS Error = 10 (No child processes).  2018-07-20 00:21:51 25983  25971 XBSA Error: (BSAGetData) A system
>   error occurred. Aborting XBSA session.  2018-07-20 00:21:51 25983 
>   25971 Informix Primary Storage Manager session 875 closed  2018-07-20
>   00:21:51 25983  25971 The child process for the backup and restore
>   filter is terminating  with exit code 0.  2018-07-20 00:21:53 25971 
>   25933 Unable to close the storage space restore: The physical restore
>   was not completed..  2018-07-20 00:21:53 25971  25933 Process 25971 
>   25933 completed.  2018-07-20 00:21:53 25933  25931 (-43246) The ON-Bar
>   process 25971 exited with a problem (exit code 131 (0x83),
>   signal 0).

Answer (score 1):

Finally had the time to make a test with `psm` and `onbar` to make an Informix backup to Amazon S3.

The test setup is 2 `CentOS 7` virtual machines (`machine1` and `machine2`) with an Informix server on each. The machines can talk to each other and with Amazon S3.
`machine1` will have Informix server `ifx_a` and `machine2`will have Informix server `ifx_b`.
Informix 12.10.FC12 was installed on each machine, using the default location (`/opt/IBM/informix/12.10/`).
It was a `root` installation, but everything else is run under user `informix`.

1. On `machine1` I setup and initialize Informix server `ifx_a`.

   - I have the following environment variables:

     ```
     PATH=/opt/IBM/informix/12.10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
     INFORMIXDIR=/opt/IBM/informix/12.10
     INFORMIXSERVER=ifx_a
     INFORMIXSQLHOSTS=/opt/IBM/informix/12.10/etc/sqlhosts
     ONCONFIG=onconfig.ifx_a
     ```
   - I have the following parameters in the `onconfig.ifx_a` file:

     ```
     ROOTNAME rootdbs
     ROOTPATH $INFORMIXDIR/tmp/demo_on.rootdbs

     SERVERNUM 1
     DBSERVERNAME ifx_a

     NETTYPE soctcp,1,50,NET

     BAR_ACT_LOG $INFORMIXDIR/tmp/bar_act.log
     BAR_DEBUG_LOG $INFORMIXDIR/tmp/bar_dbug.log
     BAR_DEBUG 5
     BAR_MAX_BACKUP 3
     BAR_RETRY 1
     BAR_PROGRESS_FREQ 10
     BAR_BSALIB_PATH $INFORMIXDIR/lib/libbsapsm.so
     BACKUP_FILTER  '/usr/bin/gzip -c'
     RESTORE_FILTER '/usr/bin/gzip -d -c'
     BAR_PERFORMANCE 3
     BAR_CKPTSEC_TIMEOUT 15
     BAR_HISTORY 0

     PSM_ACT_LOG      $INFORMIXDIR/tmp/psm_act.log
     PSM_DEBUG_LOG    $INFORMIXDIR/tmp/psm_dbug.log
     PSM_DEBUG        5
     PSM_CATALOG_PATH $INFORMIXDIR/etc/psm
     PSM_DBS_POOL     DBSPOOL
     PSM_LOG_POOL     LOGPOOL

     ALARMPROGRAM $INFORMIXDIR/etc/alarmprogram.sh
     ```
   - The `sqlhosts` file:

     ```
     ifx_a    onsoctcp    machine1.local    15010    k=1
     ifx_b    onsoctcp    machine2.local    15020    k=1
     ```
   - Create the root dbspace file and set up permissions:

     ```
     $ touch /opt/IBM/informix/12.10/tmp/demo_on.rootdbs
     $ chown informix:informix /opt/IBM/informix/12.10/tmp/demo_on.rootdbs
     $ chmod 660 /opt/IBM/informix/12.10/tmp/demo_on.rootdbs
     ```
   - Initialize the Informix server `ifx_a`:

     ```
     $ oninit -vi

     $ onstat -d

     IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 12.10.FC12 -- On-Line -- Up 00:15:50 -- 164468 Kbytes

     Dbspaces
     address          number   flags      fchunk   nchunks  pgsize   flags    owner    name
     44c23028         1        0x1        1        1        2048     N  B     informix rootdbs
      1 active, 2047 maximum

     Chunks
     address          chunk/dbs     offset     size       free       bpages     flags pathname
     44c23268         1      1      0          150000     85073                 PO-B-- /opt/IBM/informix/12.10/tmp/demo_on.rootdbs
      1 active, 32766 maximum

     NOTE: The values in the "size" and "free" columns for DBspace chunks are
           displayed in terms of "pgsize" of the DBspace to which they belong.


     Expanded chunk capacity mode: always
     ```
   - Create a new database `test_db` on the new Informix server:

     ```
     $ printf "CREATE DATABASE test_db WITH LOG;" | dbaccess sysmaster
     ```
2. Follow [Back up to Amazon Simple Storage Service using ON-Bar and the PSM](http://informix.hcldoc.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.bar.doc%2Fids_bar_onbar_amazon.htm&cp=0_1_0_7_0) and setup the Amazon S3 bucket and credentials. The following steps are based on the mentioned documentation:
3. Initialize the `psm` catalog by just using an `onpsm` command:

   ```
   $ onpsm -C detail

   The Informix Primary Storage Manager catalog is not present in the '/opt/IBM/informix/12.10/etc/psm/'
   directory.
   The system will try to create it.
   Informix Primary Storage Manager catalog creation in the '/opt/IBM/informix/12.10/etc/psm/' directory
   succeeded.

   Informix Primary Storage Manager State:

       PSM Unique ID    : 1532732188
       Catalog Location : /opt/IBM/informix/12.10/etc/psm/
       Catalog State    : Unlocked
       Catalog Owner    : 0
       Catalog Lock Mode: Regular


   Sessions:
       Session ID       Process ID
   Empty SESSION table.
   ```
4. Add the Amazon S3 bucket to the storage pools for dbspaces (**DBSPOOL**) and logical logs (**LOGPOOL**):

   - ```
     $ onpsm -D add AMAZON1 \
     -g DBSPOOL \
     -p HIGHEST \
     -t CLOUD \
     --url https://ifx-a-cloud-bucket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com \
     --provider S3 \
     --user UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU \
     --password XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \
     --container ifx-a-cloud-bucket \
     --max_part_size 25600

     $ onpsm -D add AMAZON1 \
     -g LOGPOOL \
     -p HIGHEST \
     -t CLOUD \
     --url https://ifx-a-cloud-bucket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com \
     --provider S3 \
     --user UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU \
     --password XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \
     --container ifx-a-cloud-bucket \
     --max_part_size 25600
     ```
   - ```
     $ onpsm -D list

     Informix Primary Storage Manager Device List

     Type   Prio     Block/Size (MB)  Pool Name     Device Name
     FILE   LOW          --/--        DBSPOOL       /opt/IBM/informix/12.10/backups
     CLOUD  HIGHEST      --/--        DBSPOOL       AMAZON1

     FILE   LOW          --/--        LOGPOOL       /opt/IBM/informix/12.10/backups
     CLOUD  HIGHEST      --/--        LOGPOOL       AMAZON1
     ```
   - With a recently created Amazon S3 bucket, the `url` should point to the region of the bucket, else Amazon S3 will return a temporary redirect payload and `onpsm` does not deal nicely with it (it seems to crash).
5. Make a backup of Informix server `ifx_a` (in this case I am making a whole system backup, option "-w"):

   -
           $ onbar -b -w -L 0

   - Check onbar log file at `/opt/IBM/informix/12.10/tmp/bar_act.log`:

     ```
      2018-07-28 00:45:26.596713 7539  7537 /opt/IBM/informix/12.10/bin/onbar_d -b -L 0 -w
      2018-07-28 00:45:26.757667 7539  7537 Using IBM's PSM version 12.10.FC12 as the Storage Manager. XBSA API version is 1.0.3.
      2018-07-28 00:45:26.933961 7539  7537 Archive started on rootdbs (Requested Level 0).
      2018-07-28 00:45:26.966597 7539  7537 Begin level 0 backup rootdbs.
      2018-07-28 00:45:26.966861 7539  7537 Starting Filter /usr/bin/gzip -c.
      2018-07-28 00:45:26.971701 7542  7539 Successfully connected to Storage Manager.
      2018-07-28 00:45:34.500992 7542  7539 The child process for the backup and restore filter is terminating
     with exit code 0.
      2018-07-28 00:45:34.507614 7539  7537 Successfully connected to Storage Manager.
      2018-07-28 00:45:34.511597 7539  7537 Completed level 0 backup rootdbs (Storage Manager copy ID: 0 1).
      2018-07-28 00:45:34.545924 7539  7537 Archive on rootdbs Completed (Requested Level 0).
      2018-07-28 00:45:34.549264 7539  7537 Begin backup logical log 1.
      2018-07-28 00:45:34.549524 7539  7537 Starting Filter /usr/bin/gzip -c.
      2018-07-28 00:45:34.570435 7561  7539 Successfully connected to Storage Manager.
      2018-07-28 00:45:38.455047 7561  7539 The child process for the backup and restore filter is terminating
     with exit code 0.
      2018-07-28 00:45:38.461007 7539  7537 Successfully connected to Storage Manager.
      2018-07-28 00:45:38.555035 7539  7537 Completed backup logical log 1 (Storage Manager copy ID: 0 2).
      2018-07-28 00:45:38.572049 7539  7537 Begin backup logical log 2.
      2018-07-28 00:45:38.572251 7539  7537 Starting Filter /usr/bin/gzip -c.
      2018-07-28 00:45:38.577040 7576  7539 Successfully connected to Storage Manager.
      2018-07-28 00:45:43.152739 7576  7539 The child process for the backup and restore filter is terminating
     with exit code 0.
      2018-07-28 00:45:43.159746 7539  7537 Successfully connected to Storage Manager.
      2018-07-28 00:45:43.214322 7539  7537 Completed backup logical log 2 (Storage Manager copy ID: 0 3).
      2018-07-28 00:45:43.227226 7539  7537 Begin backup logical log 3.
      2018-07-28 00:45:43.227451 7539  7537 Starting Filter /usr/bin/gzip -c.
      2018-07-28 00:45:43.231582 7592  7539 Successfully connected to Storage Manager.
      2018-07-28 00:45:46.529906 7592  7539 The child process for the backup and restore filter is terminating
     with exit code 0.
      2018-07-28 00:45:46.536171 7539  7537 Successfully connected to Storage Manager.
      2018-07-28 00:45:46.561509 7539  7537 Completed backup logical log 3 (Storage Manager copy ID: 0 4).
      2018-07-28 00:45:46.586104 7539  7537 Successfully connected to Storage Manager.
      2018-07-28 00:45:46.659232 7539  7537 Begin backup of critical file '/opt/IBM/informix/12.10/etc/ixbar.1'.
      2018-07-28 00:45:46.662166 7539  7537 Successfully connected to Storage Manager.
      2018-07-28 00:45:46.665362 7539  7537 Completed backup of critical file '/opt/IBM/informix/12.10/etc/ixbar.1' (Storage Manager copy ID: 0 5).
      2018-07-28 00:45:47.106933 7539  7537 Begin backup of critical file '/opt/IBM/informix/12.10/etc/oncfg_ifx_a.1'.
      2018-07-28 00:45:47.111936 7539  7537 Successfully connected to Storage Manager.
      2018-07-28 00:45:47.117141 7539  7537 Completed backup of critical file '/opt/IBM/informix/12.10/etc/oncfg_ifx_a.1' (Storage Manager copy ID: 0 6).
      2018-07-28 00:45:47.566010 7539  7537 Begin backup of critical file '/opt/IBM/informix/12.10/etc/onconfig.ifx_a'.
      2018-07-28 00:45:47.571084 7539  7537 Successfully connected to Storage Manager.
      2018-07-28 00:45:47.577958 7539  7537 Completed backup of critical file '/opt/IBM/informix/12.10/etc/onconfig.ifx_a' (Storage Manager copy ID: 0 7).
      2018-07-28 00:45:48.216676 7539  7537 Begin backup of critical file '/opt/IBM/informix/12.10/etc/sqlhosts'.
      2018-07-28 00:45:48.221868 7539  7537 Successfully connected to Storage Manager.
      2018-07-28 00:45:48.227252 7539  7537 Completed backup of critical file '/opt/IBM/informix/12.10/etc/sqlhosts' (Storage Manager copy ID: 0 8).
      2018-07-28 00:45:48.649965 7539  7537 /opt/IBM/informix/12.10/bin/onbar_d complete, returning 0 (0x00)
     ```
6. Setup automatic backup on completion for logical logs.

   - Edit the `ALARMPROGRAM`script and change `BACKUPLOGS` to `Y`:

     ```
     BACKUPLOGS=Y
     ```
   - Force a logical log completion/change and it will backup all logical logs that need.

     ```
     $ onmode -l
     ```
   - Check onbar log file at `/opt/IBM/informix/12.10/tmp/bar_act.log`:

     ```
     07/28/18 01:11:02  Logical Log 4 Complete, timestamp: 0x4c867.
     07/28/18 01:11:03  Logical Log 4 - Backup Started
     07/28/18 01:11:05  Logical Log 4 - Backup Completed
     07/28/18 01:11:09  Logical Log 5 Complete, timestamp: 0x55db7.
     07/28/18 01:11:10  Logical Log 5 - Backup Started
     07/28/18 01:11:12  Logical Log 5 - Backup Completed
     07/28/18 01:11:36  Logical Log 6 Complete, timestamp: 0x57a93.
     07/28/18 01:11:37  Logical Log 6 - Backup Started
     07/28/18 01:11:38  Logical Log 6 - Backup Completed
     ```
7. Verify that the backup objects are listed in the `psm` catalog:

   ```
   $ onpsm -O list

   Informix Primary Storage Manager Object List

   Object ID            Date Created         Size (MB) Logical path (name.version)
   1                    2018-07-28 00:45:26        2.5 /ifx_a/rootdbs/0/ifx_a.1
   2                    2018-07-28 00:45:34        1.2 /ifx_a/1/1/ifx_a.1
   3                    2018-07-28 00:45:38        1.4 /ifx_a/1/2/ifx_a.1
   4                    2018-07-28 00:45:43        0.9 /ifx_a/1/3/ifx_a.1
   5                    2018-07-28 00:45:46        0.0 /ifx_a/critical_files/ixbar/ifx_a.1
   6                    2018-07-28 00:45:47        0.0 /ifx_a/critical_files/oncfg/ifx_a.1
   7                    2018-07-28 00:45:47        0.1 /ifx_a/critical_files/onconfig/ifx_a.1
   8                    2018-07-28 00:45:48        0.0 /ifx_a/critical_files/sqlhosts/ifx_a.1
   9                    2018-07-28 01:11:03        0.6 /ifx_a/1/4/ifx_a.1
   10                   2018-07-28 01:11:10        0.6 /ifx_a/1/5/ifx_a.1
   11                   2018-07-28 01:11:37        0.1 /ifx_a/1/6/ifx_a.1
   ```
8. Export the `psm` catalog so it can be moved to `machine2`.

   - This will create a `psm_catalog.exp` in the current directory. It will contain text files to be imported into a new catalog.

     ```
     $ onpsm -C export
     ```
   - Another way is just to just copy the `psm` catalog to `machine2`.

     - On Informix version 12.10.FC10 the export option is broken for `CLOUD` type devices, so the catalog must be copied instead.
   - The `psm` catalog is not part of the backups. It should itself be backup up by an external tool, as per the documentation [HCL Informix Primary Storage Manager](http://informix.hcldoc.com/help/topic/com.ibm.bar.doc/ids_bar_526.htm?cp=0_1_0_4_0)
9. On `machine2` I setup Informix server `ifx_b`, but I do **not** initialize it.

   - I have the following environment variables:

     ```
     PATH=/opt/IBM/informix/12.10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
     INFORMIXDIR=/opt/IBM/informix/12.10
     INFORMIXSERVER=ifx_b
     INFORMIXSQLHOSTS=/opt/IBM/informix/12.10/etc/sqlhosts
     ONCONFIG=onconfig.ifx_b
     ```
   - I have the following parameters in the `onconfig.ifx_b` file which are mostly equal to Informix server `ifx_a`, but I prefer to give it a different SERVERNUM and DBSERVERNAME (it is not required, since they are in separate machines):

     ```
     ROOTNAME rootdbs
     ROOTPATH $INFORMIXDIR/tmp/demo_on.rootdbs

     SERVERNUM 2
     DBSERVERNAME ifx_b

     NETTYPE soctcp,1,50,NET

     BAR_ACT_LOG $INFORMIXDIR/tmp/bar_act.log
     BAR_DEBUG_LOG $INFORMIXDIR/tmp/bar_dbug.log
     BAR_DEBUG 5
     BAR_MAX_BACKUP 3
     BAR_RETRY 1
     BAR_PROGRESS_FREQ 10
     BAR_BSALIB_PATH $INFORMIXDIR/lib/libbsapsm.so
     BACKUP_FILTER  '/usr/bin/gzip -c'
     RESTORE_FILTER '/usr/bin/gzip -d -c'
     BAR_PERFORMANCE 3
     BAR_CKPTSEC_TIMEOUT 15
     BAR_HISTORY 0

     PSM_ACT_LOG      $INFORMIXDIR/tmp/psm_act.log
     PSM_DEBUG_LOG    $INFORMIXDIR/tmp/psm_dbug.log
     PSM_DEBUG        5
     PSM_CATALOG_PATH $INFORMIXDIR/etc/psm
     PSM_DBS_POOL     DBSPOOL
     PSM_LOG_POOL     LOGPOOL

     ALARMPROGRAM $INFORMIXDIR/etc/alarmprogram.sh
     ```
   - The `sqlhosts` file:

     ```
     ifx_a    onsoctcp    machine1.local    15010    k=1
     ifx_b    onsoctcp    machine2.local    15020    k=1
     ```
   - Create the root dbspace file and set up permissions:

     ```
     $ touch /opt/IBM/informix/12.10/tmp/demo_on.rootdbs
     $ chown informix:informix /opt/IBM/informix/12.10/tmp/demo_on.rootdbs
     $ chmod 660 /opt/IBM/informix/12.10/tmp/demo_on.rootdbs
     ```
10. Copy into `machine2` the Informix server `ifx_a` `psm` catalog export.
11. Import the Informix server `ifx_a` `psm` catalog. The imported catalog will assume all the same absolute paths from Informix server `ifx_a`. But both Informix servers were setup to have the same absolute paths.

    - In the directory where the `psm_catalog.exp` is, I run:

      ```
      $ onpsm -C import

       The Informix Primary Storage Manager catalog is not present in the '/opt/IBM/informix/12.10/etc/psm/'
       directory.
      The system will try to create it.
       Informix Primary Storage Manager catalog creation in the '/opt/IBM/informix/12.10/etc/psm/' directory
       succeeded.

      This option replaces the Informix Primary Storage Manager catalog using the
       contents of the
      'psm_catalog.exp' directory.
      Are you sure you want to continue? (y/n) y
      ```
    - Check the `psm` catalog:

      ```
      $ onpsm -C detail

      Informix Primary Storage Manager State:

          PSM Unique ID    : 1532739005
          Catalog Location : /opt/IBM/informix/12.10/etc/psm/
          Catalog State    : Unlocked
          Catalog Owner    : 0
          Catalog Lock Mode: Regular


      Sessions:
          Session ID       Process ID
      Empty SESSION table.


      $ onpsm -O list

      Informix Primary Storage Manager Object List

      Object ID            Date Created         Size (MB) Logical path (name.version)
      1                    2018-07-28 00:45:26        2.5 /ifx_a/rootdbs/0/ifx_a.1
      2                    2018-07-28 00:45:34        1.2 /ifx_a/1/1/ifx_a.1
      3                    2018-07-28 00:45:38        1.4 /ifx_a/1/2/ifx_a.1
      4                    2018-07-28 00:45:43        0.9 /ifx_a/1/3/ifx_a.1
      5                    2018-07-28 00:45:46        0.0 /ifx_a/critical_files/ixbar/ifx_a.1
      6                    2018-07-28 00:45:47        0.0 /ifx_a/critical_files/oncfg/ifx_a.1
      7                    2018-07-28 00:45:47        0.1 /ifx_a/critical_files/onconfig/ifx_a.1
      8                    2018-07-28 00:45:48        0.0 /ifx_a/critical_files/sqlhosts/ifx_a.1
      9                    2018-07-28 01:11:03        0.6 /ifx_a/1/4/ifx_a.1
      10                   2018-07-28 01:11:10        0.6 /ifx_a/1/5/ifx_a.1
      11                   2018-07-28 01:11:37        0.1 /ifx_a/1/6/ifx_a.1
      12                   2018-07-28 01:32:40        2.5 /ifx_a/rootdbs/0/ifx_a.2
      13                   2018-07-28 01:32:47        0.5 /ifx_a/1/7/ifx_a.1
      14                   2018-07-28 01:32:49        0.0 /ifx_a/critical_files/ixbar/ifx_a.2
      15                   2018-07-28 01:32:49        0.0 /ifx_a/critical_files/oncfg/ifx_a.2
      16                   2018-07-28 01:32:50        0.1 /ifx_a/critical_files/onconfig/ifx_a.2
      17                   2018-07-28 01:32:50        0.0 /ifx_a/critical_files/sqlhosts/ifx_a.2
      ```
12. For `onbar` to work, it needs an `ixbar` file (it´s own offline catalog). `onsmsync` command can recreate the `ixbar` file, but it can only do it from the `sysutils` database, which does not exists in Informix server `ifx_b`, since it has not been initialized (and even then, it would be empty). So we need to get it from the `psm` storage devices.

    - Get object 14 because it is the most recent backup of the ixbar file.
    - Check the object catalog metadata:

      ```
      $ onpsm -O detail -o 14

      Informix Primary Storage Manager Object Detail List

          Object ID       : 14
          XBSA PATH       : /ifx_a/critical_files/ixbar
          XBSA CopyId     : 0:14
          Object Type     : C
          Object version  : 2
          Physical pieces :
              https://ifx-a-cloud-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com//ifx_a/critical_files/ixbar/ixbar.14.1
          Number of pieces: 1
      ```
    - Get ("dump") the `ixbar` file from the storage device:

      ```
      onpsm -O dump -o 14
      ```
    - It creates a file `ifx_a_critical_files_ixbar.14` on the current directory. Copy and rename the file to the become the `ixbar` file for the Informix server `ifx_b` (SERVERNUM 2):

      ```
      $ cp ifx_a_critical_files_ixbar.14 /opt/IBM/informix/12.10/etc/ixbar.2
      ```
13. Launch the `onbar` restore command.

    $ onbar -r -w

    - Check onbar log file at `/opt/IBM/informix/12.10/tmp/bar_act.log`:

      ```
       2018-07-28 01:57:45.727270 11009  11007 /opt/IBM/informix/12.10/bin/onbar_d -r -w
       2018-07-28 01:57:45.794570 11009  11007 Using IBM's PSM version 12.10.FC12 as the Storage Manager. XBSA API version is 1.0.3.
       2018-07-28 01:57:45.799655 11009  11007 Successfully connected to Storage Manager.
       2018-07-28 01:57:45.799874 11009  11007 Starting Filter /usr/bin/gzip -d -c.
       2018-07-28 01:57:45.831695 11011  11009 Successfully connected to Storage Manager.
       2018-07-28 01:57:46.435703 11009  11007 Begin reserved pages read (level 0 of rootdbs, Storage Manager copy ID: 0 12).
       2018-07-28 01:57:46.486687* 11011  11009 Filter closed.
       2018-07-28 01:57:46.531063* 11011  11009 Filter closed.
       2018-07-28 01:57:46.540890 11009  11007 Completed reserved pages read (level 0 of rootdbs).
       2018-07-28 01:57:46.555287 11009  11007 Unable to start logical log salvage: Unable to read boot strap config file - '/opt/IBM/informix/12.10/etc/oncfg_ifx_b.2' .
       2018-07-28 01:57:51.563908 11009  11007 Successfully connected to Storage Manager.
       2018-07-28 01:57:51.564216 11009  11007 Starting Filter /usr/bin/gzip -d -c.
       2018-07-28 01:57:51.575587 11019  11009 Successfully connected to Storage Manager.
       2018-07-28 01:57:52.096184 11009  11007 Begin reserved pages read (level 0 of rootdbs, Storage Manager copy ID: 0 12).
       2018-07-28 01:57:52.153351* 11019  11009 Filter closed.
       2018-07-28 01:57:52.198363* 11019  11009 Filter closed.
       2018-07-28 01:57:52.209302 11009  11007 Completed reserved pages read (level 0 of rootdbs).
       2018-07-28 01:57:52.222134 11009  11007 Successfully connected to Storage Manager.
       2018-07-28 01:57:52.222251 11009  11007 Starting Filter /usr/bin/gzip -d -c.
       2018-07-28 01:57:52.227977 11024  11009 Successfully connected to Storage Manager.
       2018-07-28 01:57:52.753398 11009  11007 Begin cold level 0 restore rootdbs (Storage Manager copy ID: 0 12).
       2018-07-28 01:58:05.396340 11024  11009 The child process for the backup and restore filter is terminating
      with exit code 0.
       2018-07-28 01:58:05.448496 11009  11007 Completed cold level 0 restore rootdbs.
       2018-07-28 01:58:05.790012 11009  11007 Completed whole system restore.
       2018-07-28 01:58:06.812501 11009  11007 Successfully connected to Storage Manager.
       2018-07-28 01:58:06.812747 11009  11007 Starting Filter /usr/bin/gzip -d -c.
       2018-07-28 01:58:06.827447 11049  11009 Successfully connected to Storage Manager.
       2018-07-28 01:58:07.413841 11009  11007 Begin restore logical log 7 (Storage Manager copy ID: 0 13).
       2018-07-28 01:58:09.251399 11049  11009 The child process for the backup and restore filter is terminating
      with exit code 0.
       2018-07-28 01:58:09.382900 11009  11007 Completed restore logical log 7.
       2018-07-28 01:58:09.388014 11009  11007 Successfully connected to Storage Manager.
       2018-07-28 01:58:09.831410 11009  11007 Completed logical restore.
       2018-07-28 01:58:10.046783 11009  11007 Successfully connected to Storage Manager.
       2018-07-28 01:58:10.104630 11009  11007 /opt/IBM/informix/12.10/bin/onbar_d complete, returning 0 (0x00)
      ```
    - Check online log file at `/opt/IBM/informix/12.10/tmp/online.log`:

      ```
      01:57:53  IBM Informix Dynamic Server Started.
      01:57:53  Requested shared memory segment size rounded from 4308KB to 4796KB

      Sat Jul 28 01:57:55 2018

      07/28/18 01:57:55  Requested shared memory segment size rounded from 110629KB to 110632KB
      07/28/18 01:57:55  Successfully added a bufferpool of page size 2K.

      07/28/18 01:58:00  Restartable Restore has been ENABLED
      07/28/18 01:58:00  Recovery Mode
      07/28/18 01:58:01  Listen thread init SUCCESS
      07/28/18 01:58:01  Physical Restore of rootdbs started.

      07/28/18 01:58:02  Chunk 1 '/opt/IBM/informix/12.10/tmp/demo_on.rootdbs' is sparse - inflating...
      07/28/18 01:58:09  Logical Recovery has reached the transaction cleanup phase.
      07/28/18 01:58:09  Logical Recovery Complete.
                8 Committed, 0 Rolled Back, 0 Open, 0 Bad Locks

      07/28/18 01:58:09  Logical Recovery Complete.
      07/28/18 01:58:09  Quiescent Mode
      07/28/18 01:58:09  Checkpoint Completed:  duration was 0 seconds.
      07/28/18 01:58:09  Sat Jul 28 - loguniq 8, logpos 0x18, timestamp: 0x5f8dd Interval: 25

      07/28/18 01:58:09  Maximum server connections 0
      07/28/18 01:58:09  Checkpoint Statistics - Avg. Txn Block Time 0.000, # Txns blocked 0, Plog used 19, Llog used 1

      07/28/18 01:58:10  Booting Language <spl> from module <>
      07/28/18 01:58:10  Loading Module <SPLNULL>
      07/28/18 01:58:10  Defragmenter cleaner thread now running
      07/28/18 01:58:10  Defragmenter cleaner thread cleaned:0 partitions
      ```
14. The Informix Server `ifx_b` is now in `Quiescent` mode (memory is initialized, it can perform some administrative tasks). Change the Informix server `ifx_b` to online mode.

    - ```
       $ onmode -m
      ```
    - Check that the database `test_db` was restored.

      ```
      printf "select name from sysdatabases;" | dbaccess sysmaster

      Database selected.

      name  sysmaster
      name  sysutils
      name  sysuser
      name  sysadmin
      name  test_db

      5 row(s) retrieved.

      Database closed.
      ```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Luis. I got stuck here: onpsm -O dump -o 457. I have edited your answer to include details of the error due to lack of space in comment

Comment: @gbaz I did some testing and posted my step by step. Maybe it can help.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed, and prompt, response; I really appreciate it. Looking at the setup I have and yours the one main difference I see is using the ALARMPROGRAM script for logical backups. Is it possible to just setup a cron jobs to perform full level 0 backups hourly with `onbar -b -L0 -w` followed by `onbar -b -l` every 5 minutes for logical logs without relying on the **alarmprogram.sh** script? If so, how would the recovery process look like?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You should also do an `onmode -l` to switch to the next logical before the `onbar -b -l`, because `onbar` will not backup logical logs that are still `CURRENT`. The restore, with the Informix server stopped (a cold restore) is simply using `onbar -r`. It will restore the most recent whole system backup (`onbar -b -w -L 0`) and then restore all logical logs up to the most recent.

Comment: I looked at the ontape tool and it seems easier to do `ontape -s -L 0 -d` then `ontape -c` for continuous backups and do a s3 sync for the TAPEDEV and LTAPEDEV directories without having to worry about backing up sysutils database  and all.

Comment: Yes, it will also work. However `ontape` is a `serial` type of backup, as only 1 process is streaming the dbspaces, so it will take longer than `onbar`, that can use multiple parallel streams. Usually when the Informix instance reaches a certain dimension, `onbar` is used to keep backup times at reasonable levels. You can also use `ontape` on the `alarmprgram.sh` script, instead of `ontape -c` as is described here:  [Starting a continuous logical-log file backup](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_11.70.0/com.ibm.bar.doc/ids_bar_311.htm).

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I have one last question regarding the ontape tool: when using ontape to backup to a directory, is there a native way to automatically remove older backup files (be it L0, L1, or logical logs)? I am doing an S3 sync from TAPEDEV and LTAPEDEV directories and would like to delete older backups from the local backup directory to avoid it filling up the drive. While I could do it with a shell script and a cron job I was hoping the tool had a native option of doing so

Comment: Not that I am aware. The only thing `ontape` does is renaming the previous backup file so it is not overwritten. You will have to script a cron job to remove older `LX` backups and the logical logs backups. Also, the documentation advises to keep a copy of the `onconfig` file, which `ontape` does not backup [Keep a copy of your configuration file](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.bar.doc/ids_bar_467.htm) .